# How to hide or show Action bar on touch event

Tags: android, android-viewpager, touch-event, android-fullscreen

Here I am, using a view pager on this I set `onTouchListner`.

I want when a simple click is made on View pager it should hide or show Action bar and other layouts and when touched again show them. I also want to use `Sliding effect` of view pager.

Here is what I have done so far.

```
viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            onTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
    });

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {   
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        downX = event.getX();
        downY = event.getY();
        return true;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        upX = event.getX();
        upY = event.getY();
        float deltaX = downX - upX;
        float deltaY = downY - upY;
        // swipe horizontal?
        if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
            // left or right
            if (deltaX < 0) {
                Toast("Left to right");
                openPreviousPage();
                return true;
            }
            if (deltaX > 0) {
                Toast("ight to left");
                openNextPage();
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) < 15) {
                toggleFullScreen();
            }

        }

        return true;
    }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And to hide action bar and other layouts I'm using `SystemUiHider`.

Here is what I'm doing to hide it

```
mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, bottomRL, HIDER_FLAGS);
    mSystemUiHider.setup();

mSystemUiHider
            .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                // Cached values.
                int mControlsHeight;
                int mShortAnimTime;

                @Override
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                        // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                        // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                        // screen.
                        if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                            mControlsHeight = bottomRL.getHeight();
                        }
                        if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                            mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                    android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                        }
                        bottomRL.animate()
                                .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                    } else {
                        if (visible) {
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                            bottomRL.setLayoutParams(params);
                            bottomRL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            // getActionBar().show();
                        } else {
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                            viewPager.setLayoutParams(params);
                            getActionBar().hide();
                            viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                    if (visible) {
                        // Schedule a hide().
                        // delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                    }
                }
            });
```

The problem is this that when I touch view pager it hides the action bar and other layout i.e now I'm in full screen mode. But now if I try to swipe view pager it shows the Action bar first and then after swiping it swipes to next screen

Kindly help me with this I'm struck badly.
Thanks in advance.